# Is there any way to show some Post's ACF fields within others?

Tags: wordpress

Let me start from scratch to describe what I need:

I have a website about games and I want to get some kind of database, so that players can search/filter it (by year, by genre, by platforms, etc.).

What I came to: I store the games in a separate post-type 'games', for them I added to ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) a group of fields with the data I needed (Release date, Genre, Platform, etc.).

I want to do what is called a "game list" (you know various lists Games about pirates, Games about space, tons and tons of lists, so no - it is not category): this is most likely a post in which I want to be able, for example, to do this:

```
<post content>
Some useful text ...

<h2> Some Headline </ h2>

// this can be a shortcode or block in guttenberg, I'm not very good. specialist
[insert-game-info id = "1"]

Just a couple paragraph of cool text useful for SEO

[insert-game-info id = "2"]

Lyalyalya, and still text, and behind him again game

[insert-game-info id = "3"]
</ post content>
```

How to make such a thing? It is clear that it is very necessary that there be some kind of dialogue that allows you to choose from the list of games.

I'm researching whether there is already solution, for me it seems that it must be common problem

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your proficiency, I would recommend using the WordPress [get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) function and return the field data with ACF's [get_field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) inside of the foreach.

ACF's [get_field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) allows you to get a value from a specific post like so:

```
$value = get_field( "text_field", 123 );
```

Comment: I thought that this scenario is common for many websites, so I don't want to reinvent existing wheel. With this approach I will write all this stuff from scratch: shortcode, dialog to select posts, etc